# PHP date_timezone_set stops date format from showing 24hr time

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code:

```
$date = date_create('2014-11-06T23:00:00.000Z');
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Australia/Victoria'));
echo $date ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And it results in:

```
2014-11-07 10:00:00
```

However in the PHP doco here it says that capital H is 24hr time:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

If I comment out the middle line as follows:

```
$date = date_create('2014-11-06T23:00:00.000Z');
#date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Australia/Victoria'));
echo $date ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It results in:

```
2014-11-06 23:00:00
```

Which does show 24hr time, but the date is a day out, which is why I need to set the timezone.

Why does setting the date_timezone_set stop me from being able to show the date in 24hr time format, and how to do fix this?

Comment: `10` is 10 in the morning.

Comment: ok cool... thanks boys...  yes the offset threw me I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a timezone `date_create` assumes the current timezone. If you don't define one then it will use UTC.

Since the timezone is specified after the `date_create` the date is stored as UTC.

Since 2014-11-06 23:00 UTC is the same time as 2014-11-07 10:00 UTC+11 (Australia/Victoria) you will see the latter when you 'echo' the date.

Comment: `If you don't define one then it will use UTC.` is not true. If date-string already has defined timezone, you cannot set it to other with 2nd parameter. Try it... Or se note [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: I wanted to delete this question as the issue was an error on my part....  but I can't see how to delete a question anywhere....